# When clicking browser back button it duplicates history while using iframe in react route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, browser, react-router

I'm facing a weird bug while using an `iframe` in one route in my company react app.

I have route for `"/home"` and `"/maintenance"`, `"/maintenance"` uses `iframe`. When I am in `"/maintenance"` route and click browser back button to take me to home page, it shows homepage overlapping maintenance page.

I tried using key attribute in `iframe` it didn't work. Please let me know if anyone have found solution for this.